# What percentage of international flights departing from Manila are cancelled due to Duterte's lockdown on Metro Manila from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14?

Tags: international-travel, cancellations, philippines, covid-19, manila

What percentage of international flights departing from Manila airport (MNL) are cancelled because of [Duterte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigo_Duterte)'s lockdown on Metro Manila because of COVID-19 from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14?

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNnPXB
- https://redd.it/fifmjo

---

Since one individual closed the question, I'll post the answer here. Feel free to edit it by either amending my text or adding your own section:

### Answer

I haven't seen any major cancellation so far between 2020-03-15 and 2020-03-19 for international departing from MNL From 2020-03-20 00:00 all flights were supposed to be canceled according to the "enhanced" lockdown announced on 2020-03-16 evening but the ban was later lifted for non-Filipino citizens on 2020-03-18.

https://mnlairport.ph/flights/cancellations lists flights cancellations.

### Before 2020-03-19:

https://cnnphilippines.com/business/2020/3/13/airasia-suspends-flights-.html:

> PAL [Philippines Airlines]'s international flights from Manila will continue during the period, it added.

https://newsroom.airasia.com/news/2020/3/13/updated-as-of-13-march-2020-travel-advisory-airasia-cancels-domestic-flights-from-manila-as-ph-government-implements-new-travel-restrictions: only mentions domestic flight from/to MNL cancellations.

[image]

https://www.manila-airport.net/naia-departures?day=tomorrow ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200314090136/https://www.manila-airport.net/naia-departures?day=tomorrow)) doesn't seem to show any cancellation, but weirdly domestic flights aren't canceled either, so I doubt it is accurate.

https://newsroom.airasia.com/news/2020/3/13/updated-as-of-13-march-2020-travel-advisory-airasia-cancels-domestic-flights-from-manila-as-ph-government-implements-new-travel-restrictions:

> [Updated as of 14 March 2020] Travel Advisory: AirAsia cancels **domestic** flights from Manila as PH government implements new travel restrictions

### From 2020-03-20:

https://www.rappler.com/business/254885-philippine-airlines-cebu-pacific-airasia-flight-cancelations-coronavirus-luzon-lockdown:

> The airline will announce the status of its international flights from March 20 to April 12 at a later date, as it coordinates with authorities.

https://www.pna.gov.ph/articles/1096970:

> The Department of Tourism (DOT) has lauded the lifting of the travel ban on outbound passengers, except Filipino tourists, in line with the Luzon-wide enhanced community quarantine.

Comment: While a question you feel the need for, I think this is very limited in usefulness for the site. You could ask this as a separate question for each airport in many countries. And the answer may also change many times as airlines work out what is needed.

Comment: @Willeke The lockdown affects over 12 million people, and very few areas have such a lockdown. Many questions posted here  don't concern 12 million people.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt In practice, how will it help you to know the answer? Especially given it is likely to change.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt This https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/asia/coronavirus-philippines-duterte-manila-lockdown-domestic-travel-12532396 refers only to domestic travel? And this https://amp.rappler.com/nation/254361-questions-filipinos-metro-manila-coronavirus-lockdown states:

’The IATF resolution stated that “land, domestic air, and domestic sea travel to and from Metro Manila” will be suspended during the lockdown.’

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too detailed, the answer is too likely to change often. And it would be a bad sample as many like questions can be expected.

Comment: [What is our stance on questions specific to one airport? On-topic or off-topic as too specific?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6519/1810) +  [What is our stance on questions on airlines/governments' activities/policies pertaining to COVID-19? On-topic or off-topic as too ephemeral?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6520/1810)

Comment: Please stop updating this 'question' or it gets deleted as 'not a question anymore'.

Comment: @Willeke how about you reopen and I can write the answer as an answer?

Comment: In one word: "No".

Comment: @Willeke the question has many views,  it's a pity you unilaterally decided not to authorize users to add an answer. Also, similar questions are still open, so it's annoying not to have some consistency in terms of how questions are closed on this website