# Are layover currently allowed as of 20th of March 2020 In Taipei and Manila airport?

Tags: airports, taiwan, philippines, taipei

I am planning to flight from Brisbane to Osaka and wondering if it was possible to layover at Taipei or Manila airport?

Answer (score 2):

Yes for Manila. https://www.pna.gov.ph/articles/1096970:

> The Department of Tourism (DOT) has lauded the lifting of the travel ban on outbound passengers, except Filipino tourists, in line with the Luzon-wide enhanced community quarantine.

FYI: [What percentage of international flights departing from Manila are cancelled due to Duterte's lockdown on Metro Manila from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154940/1810)

Layovers at Taipei TPE were possible on 2020-03-12 but I don't know the current situation (because of [How can I know ahead of time whether the Taiwanese immigration and airline flying there will accept my passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155092/1810..).)

---

Update (2020-03-23): https://www.reddit.com/r/digitalnomad/comments/fnhs89/psa_for_americans_looking_to_extend_visa_in/flapex9/:

> Singapore and Taiwan are both blocking anyone from transiting starting March 24.